# Strange errror while using find in batch script

Tags: linux, shell, find, xargs

I'm trying this piece of code to resize jpg files inside folder recursively larger than 1 MB.

```
find . -type f -size +1M -name "*.jpg" | xargs convert -resize 1000x1000\> -verbose
```

Getting error message (which breaks batch after 15-20 iterations)

```
xargs: convert: terminated by signal 9
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: This is going to pass multiple filenames to `convert` which I don't think it handles correctly. Are you sure this is doing what you want and not stomping over a good chunk of your original files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xargs from my experience aren't working good in all cases, just as a proposition, try to use -exec, if you need fast solution to the problem

```
find . -type f -size +1M -name "*.jpg" -exec convert {} -resize 1000x1000\> -verbose {} \;
```

See if it will be helpful for you

Comment: What if I need two `{}`'s?

Answer (score 0):

xargs does not work properly if you have files with spaces in the name. In order for this to stand a chance of working, you should use the following syntax:

```
find . -type f -size +1M -name "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 convert -resize 1000x1000\> -verbose
```

This will insert null characters as separators instead of using spaces as separators.